# Problema com código JS (Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom, tenho um código de um chatbox em pop-up, porem ele está dando o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Código:

```
 //Variáveis a editar
var imagen_chatbox_desplegable = "http://i45.servimg.com/u/f45/17/45/19/77/chat10.png";
var posicion_chatbox_desplegable = "derecha"; // ou 'izquierda'
//Fim das variáveis a editar

document.write("<div id="chatbox_ret_cont" class="chatbox_" + posicion_chatbox_desplegable + "">");
document.write("    <div onclick="(document.getElementById('chatbox_ret').style.display=='block')?my_setcookie('chatbox_ret','0',0,0):my_setcookie('chatbox_ret','1',1,0); jQuery('#chatbox_ret').toggle('normal');">");
document.write("        <span id="chatbox_ret_online">");
document.write("            <img title="Abrir e fechar o chatbox" src="" + imagen_chatbox_desplegable + "">");
document.write("        <\/span>");
document.write("        <span id="chatbox_ret_offline"><\/span>");
document.write("    <\/div>");
document.write("    <iframe src="\/chatbox" id="chatbox_ret" name="chatbox_ret" ");
document.write("       scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="1px"");
document.write("       onload="if(cb_new){cb_start();cb_new=0;}">");
document.write("    <\/iframe>");
document.write("<\/div>");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você tem que *escapar* as aspas duplas dentro de um string de aspas duplas, exemplo:

```
"\"string dentro de uma string\""
```

Então no seu código:

```
document.write("<div id="chatbox_ret_cont" class="chatbox_" + posicion_chatbox_desplegable + "">");
```

Tem que ficar:

```
document.write("<div id=\"chatbox_ret_cont\" class=\"chatbox_" + posicion_chatbox_desplegable + "\">");
```

Você também pode trocar por aspas simples:

```
document.write('<div id="chatbox_ret_cont"></div>');
```

---

Sobre o uso do método [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write), não é recomendável usa-lo, pois qualquer outro conteúdo já criado no documento será apagado. Se você está mesmo usando jQuery crie esse html em uma string e use o [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) para criar a estrutura no DOM.

Comment: Infelizmente, ficou na mesma e continua com o mesmo erro: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list   / código atual: http://pastebin.com/g1Xg5ftj

Comment: @FábioMiguel cara, você copiou a 6ª linha de forma errada, o correto é: `document.write("<div id='chatbox_ret_cont' class='chatbox_" + posicion_chatbox_desplegable + "'>");`. A 9ª também está errada: `document.write("            <img title='Abrir e fechar o chatbox' src='" + imagen_chatbox_desplegable + "'>");`. E a 11ª também.

Comment: Corrigi essas linhas, porem ocorreu mais erros, sendo estes: /+%20imagen_chatbox_desplegable%20+ Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   e   Uncaught ReferenceError: cb_new is not defined   / código atual: http://pastebin.com/FERFL9m9

Comment: @FábioMiguel cara, provavelmente sua variável `cb_new` não existe no momento em que é usada e na `img` que você tentou concatenar o valor da variável `imagen_chatbox_desplegable` na verdade você concatenou o nome dela, por isso a imagem não foi achada. Eu já expliquei o erro e o porque dele, e também como corrigir. Acho que tá na hora de você dar uma lida melhor no seu código e tentar resolver isso por si só, já que são erros básicos de sintaxe. Não posso ficar aqui corrigindo todo erro que você tiver, até porque dessa forma você não vai aprender a corrigi-los.

Comment: Tens razão. De qualquer maneira, obrigado pela ajuda prestada ^^